# Copiar e Colar no powershell, para automatização de tarefas

Tags: powershell

Como Copiar e Colar no powershell, para automatização de tarefas

Comment: Sorry, eu estava iniciando no stackoverflow, não é uma pergunta, e sim uma afirmação, irei excluir a pergunta. kkkk

Comment: Obrigado! Irei Fazer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Computadores antigos, com o PowerShell numa versão mais antigas do que a versão 5, use:

```PowerShell
"Hello World" | clip
```

---

Já na versão 5 ou posterior, use:

Para Copiar

```PowerShell
Set-Clipboard -Value "Hello World"
```

Para colar

```PowerShell
Get-Clipboard
```